# Apache Camel File component "idempotentRepository" option versus the Idempotent Consumer processor?

Tags: java, apache-camel

In the documentation for the [File component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html), I see that we can create an idempotent read lock by specifying the `idempotent` option like this:

```
from("file://inbox?idempotent=true&idempotentRepository=#messageIdRepo")
    .to("file:data/outbox");
```

But in the documentation for [Idempotent Consumers](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html), I see that we can also specify an idimpotent processor like this:

```
from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
    .idempotentConsumer(header("CamelFileName"), someMessageIdRepository)
    .to("file:data/outbox");
```

Is there some significant behavioural difference between these two ways to create an Idempotent Consumer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference: The first is executed before reading the file, the second after. This is significant especially when downloading large files from an FTP consumer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is significant behavioural between this two ways, except that you can declare more options by using idempotentConsumer